# PHP - round() function with two decimals even whole numbers

Tags: php

How can I have two decimals values even with the whole number using round() function of php

**SAMPLE**

```
$number = round(123.456,2); // if i use number format it will not round the decimals so it will print 123.45 not 123.46
$number2 = round(123,2);
echo $number; // => 123.46
echo $number2; // => I want this one to print 123.00
```

Comment: I would recommend reviewing the **entire** PHP documentation page for rounding because one of many answers are there: http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$number2 = number_format(123, 2, '.', '');
```

Rounding a whole number wont return 2 decimal places. So use `number_format();` to make it display them.